# Django tables 2 exclude doesn't work

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.8.7 with djangotables2 1.3.0.
I'm trying to build a table using ModelForm (example below). When I try to hide a column using exclude, it still shows all columns. Exclude doesn't seem to have any effect here.

A part of my models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField (max_length = 45, blank = False, null = False)
    Date = models.DateTimeField (auto_now_add=True)
    Text = models.CharField (max_length = 64, blank = False, null = False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-Date", "Name"]
        verbose_name = "Event"
        verbose_name_plural = "Events"
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Name


class Event_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Event
        exclude = ('Date',)
```

A part of my views.py:

```
def dbtest_event(request,):
    return render(request, 'dbtest_event.html', {"Title":"Events",
    'dbtest_event':Event.objects.all()})
```

And the html-file that uses the table:

```
{% extends "dbtest.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    {% render_table dbtest_event %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas!

Comment: I don't see why the exclude values from the ModelForm's meta would automatically get translated to the Table's meta. Can you post the code where your table is defined? i.e. something that subclasses `django_tables2.Table`?

Comment: The table isn't really created anywhrere as far as I know. I'll update the question with a part of my views.py and the html-file, that's everything that has to do with the table I think.

Comment: Are you just using the `{% render_table %}` tag?

Comment: Yes, I just use that to create the table in the html-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view code doesn't actually reference the `Event_Form` class, so there's no reason your exclusion would be paid attention to.

From the docs http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html:

> While simple, passing a queryset directly to {% render_table %} doesn’t allow for any customisation. For that, you must define a custom Table class

so you must define your table explicitly

```
class EventTable(django_tables2.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = ('Date',)
```

Then make sure your table is available in your template context

```
def dbtest_event(request,):
    table = EventTable(Events.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'dbtest_event.html', {
        "Title":"Events",
        'dbtest_event_table': table,
    })
```

(If you don't need pagination or filtering based on GET parameters, then the `RequestConfig` line can be omitted.)

And finally use `{% render_table dbtest_event_table %}`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I have a last question: Is it possible to do this with the ID instead of Date? I tried it your way but it didn't work. I think that's because the database defined that attribute not me.

Comment: Did you use `id` in lower case (it's shown as 'ID' in the table heading, but the attribute name in Python is `id`)?

Comment: That was it, now it works fine. Thanks for your help!